# Making Css3 Transitions work on Page Load

Tags: css, css-transitions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [css3 transition animation on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805482/css3-transition-animation-on-load)

I would like to animate the progress bar on the page load from 0% to say 60%.Please find my fiddle below. I tried with css transition property, Couldn't achieve it.

http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/5zJPr/2/

I have already achieved it using Jquery. Please find the fiddle below.
http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/5zJPr/3/

I would like to know if it could be possible using CSS3 solution only? 
If Not CSS3 animation can't be possible on page load ? Could some one clearly explain why CSS forces to wait for an event in the page say hover or click for the animation to happen rather make it work on page load?

Thanks

Comment: The transition is event based, which means it's not working w/o any JS after page load. You need something like a `:hover` or something else, to make it work. I recommend using JS in this case.

Maybe someone else can disconfirm this.

Comment: Thanks Sn0opy. Actually I want to achieve it without  hover as per my requirement on the page load.

Comment: What about completely using Javascript? Since you want it as fallback, you can also use it for every browser.

Comment: Thanks Sn0opy I achieved the same using Jquery. Please let me know we could achieve this only using CSS3

http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/5zJPr/3/

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Bram Vanroy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using a CSS3 animation, but careful – they're not widely supported. [Here's an updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5zJPr/4/)

```css
animation: width <duration> <easing>;

@keyframes width {
    from { width: 0%; }
    to   { width: 60%; }
}​
```

Comment: Thanks minitech exactly the thing I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

Without JavaScript or jQuery, this is not possible.

Comment: Ok I will wait for others opinion, if not I ll go with your answer.Thanks