# How to remove the default font in the browser while loading @font-face in CSS? "FOUT"

Tags: css, font-face

I am loading two external fonts to my web page using @font-face. They are loading perfect in Chrome but when I try in IE the browser displays some default font while the page is loading, then the fonts are changing to the correct ones according to my css @font-face.

How can I remove the default font from showing up in IE and other browsers while the page is loading? I want to remove the so called FOUT (flash of unstyled text). I there any way to do it through the style sheet?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: user1577346, since my answer works for you, please **accept** that answer which will place a green checkmark on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For the default browser font that you don't want, set the `font-size` CSS property to `0px` and ensure you have declared the `font-size` in your `@font-face` class name CSS ***rules***.

If you also want to tackle this using a dedicated script to address this issue (Firefox 3.5/3.6 or Internet Explorer 7-9), check out the [**FOUT-B-Gone**](http://www.webink.com/fout-b-gone/) JavaScript solution.

Comment: this would work but I'd want a fallback with a feature detector like modernizr just in case font-face isn't available and you can give the font-size a positive value

Comment: You can always revert the font-size during the font fall-back rules of the webpage, but that's a different requirement that the OP might not need.

Comment: Are you sure `font-size` is allowed in `@font-face`? It isn't listed in http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-prop-desc

Comment: @atlavis, I've clarified my answer to avoid confusion. Also, you can literately use [**`font-size-adjust`**](http://www.miltonbayer.com/font-face/#adjust) CSS rule property for the `@font-face` CSS rule too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS transition to fade your text in after N milliseconds or whatever you feel is sufficient to load the font assets.  [css3 transition animation on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805482/css3-transition-animation-on-load)

Comment: Not a good answer. The link you provides shows how to `fade-out` the text during mouse `hover` event.

Comment: Posting a link to some other SO Question without providing any relevant code that actually answers this question is a no-go and is typically done as a comment.