# CSS Transition Works On Hover But Not When Class Added

Tags: html, css, sass, css-transitions

I have a simple anchor button:

```
<a href="/our-news" class="SectionNavButton">
    <span class="SectionNavButton-Inner">
</a>
```

I would like the background colour of `SectionNavButton-Inner` to transition when its parent `SectionNavButton`is hovered over/off and when a class of `active` is added to it (the parent).

My Sass:

```
.SectionNavButton
{
    .SectionNavButton-Inner
    {
        @include transition(background 0.4s ease-in-out);
        background: $style-default-link-color;
    }

    &:hover,
    &.active
    {
        .SectionNavButton-Inner
        {
            background: $style-default-link-hover-color;
        }
    }
}
```

This works great for hover, but there is no transition when I add an `active` class to the `SectionNavButton` (though the background colour does change).

**Why is there no transition when I add a class of `active` to the `SectionNavButton`?**

Comment: Do you want the transition to happen when the page is loaded? Here is a JSfiddle that may helps you: http://jsfiddle.net/4W82d/ and while we are at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805482/css3-transition-animation-on-load

Comment: Hi @Pedr, I tried threw your code into jsfiddle and it seems to work fine for me (on Chrome). I see the transition on hover and when class active is added. See [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZS6pr/)

Comment: @MartinTurjak Thanks for that. Looks like it's context specific. Seems to be some kind of conflict arising from a transition on a parent element.