# CSS transition property triggering on page load

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm exploring CSS animations. I've been developing in [codepen](http://codepen.io/wbar8417/full/dyLnF/) and moving code manually to [my server](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~wjbarlow/) when I'm happy with the result. Several elements on the page use the `transition` property in order to animate.

On codepen, my code behaves as I expect, but when I move it to my server, all of the transitions are triggered as the page loads: my nav elements drop down from the top of the screen, my banner expands to fill its space, etc. If I view the same files locally, the animation on page load doesn't happen.

Why am I getting this behavior, and how can I stop it?

Comment: this is not a duplicate. the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805482/css3-transition-animation-on-load is asking how to animate on page load, while i am asking to *stop* animation on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Add class="pageload" to your body tag (or any class name, that's just one I use for the example
)

```
body.pageload * {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -ms-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;
}
```

and remove that class after the page has loaded

```
$("window").load(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("pageload");
});
```

Comment: i'd like to avoid using javascript or jquery.

Comment: keyframes to delay the animation perhaps