# How to transition an image once only when page loads?

Tags: css, dreamweaver, onload, transition

I have an image in a table positioned like this:

```
<img src="images/home/dress.png" alt="dress" width="138" height="344" class="homeimg">
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.homeimg {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(../images/home/dress.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top: 97px;
    left: 500px;
    width: 138px;
    max-height: 344px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

I want this image to transition **only once** when the page initially loads. Not on `click` or `hover`...

```
left: 16px;
```

...and fade in from completely invisible to visible.

Comment: Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805482/css3-transition-animation-on-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `animation` instead of a `transition` and define `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to retain last animation frame

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNpyvm

```
.homeimg {
   position: absolute;
   ...
   -webkit-animation: appear 1s;
   animation: appear 1s;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes appear {
   0% { left: 500px; opacity: 0; }
   100% { left: 16px; opacity: 1; }  
}

@keyframes appear {
   0% { left: 500px; opacity: 0; }
   100% { left: 16px; opacity: 1; }  
}
```

The animation will run just once