# css transition from right to left on click with css

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make the css for right to left div when it will open but i dont want use any java script and jquery only need pure css.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could use key-frames. See this answer for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805482/css3-transition-animation-on-load

Comment: Sorry but this is not what i was looking

Comment: i need the exactly i draw the picture

Comment: Please explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: see the picture there is a navigation and when i will click on that content should box should be come from right side and current content section should be go left side

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS animation over the `clip` property

> [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBEJaB?editors=1100)

---

**Markup**

```
<section>
  <div>
    <h1>Right to Left opening</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
section { 
  position: relative;
}

div { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;  
  background: #6698F5;
  clip: rect(0, 100vw, auto, 100vw);
  animation: slide 1.5s linear 1s forwards; 
}

@keyframes slide {
  100% { clip: rect(0, 100vw, auto, 0); }
}
```

Comment: can you make like a design i attached you are almost there but its not complete working i need the section are in container and a navigation

Comment: I gave you an idea about how to obtain the effect, just apply it to your code

Comment: but if i will go in next like i am on homepage and now i want to go for about us the previews content area should be hidden for left side and new content area will come from right side

Comment: @BhupinderKumar The question has been answered, SO is not here to design or do your work for you.

Comment: I've just reported the OP for plagiarism. He copied my full answer without giving attribution and he posted the answer with another account. Then he accepted (and probably also upvoted) his own answer. I do believe this is an unfair and disrespectful behaviour.