# Transition for Text

Tags: html, css

I really love transition in html but i do not know how to do a transition with text or h2. I know for images as it is

```
    img {
        opacity:0;
        -moz-transition: opacity 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
        -webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-transition: opacity 2s;
        transition: opacity 2s;
        }
```

then

```
<img onload="this.style.opacity='1';" src="https://s13.postimg.org/6p9r8rtrr/fgh.jpg" style="width:640px;height:360px;"/>
```

The Problem is when i try this with h2 or text it doesn't work:

```
    h2 {
       opacity:0;
       -moz-transition: opacity 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
       -webkit-transition: opacity 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -o-transition: opacity 2s;
       transition: opacity 2s;
       }
```

then

```
<h2 onload="this.style.opacity='1';">What Person/Character are you thinking of?</h2>
```

But this doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `onload` doesn't work for `h2` it is only for whole document, images, scripts and other resources.

Comment: why use `onload` for text directly apply with in a css.pictures are  take a time for loading.but text not like that.and onload not support with text

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805482/css3-transition-animation-on-load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pictures take some time to load, but text doesn't have same behavior and `onload` isn't currently supported by text elements.
Check out CSS3 animation effects for elements on [**W3schools tutorial**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

**Snippet**

```css
h2 {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadein 2s forwards;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<h2>What Person/Character are you thinking of?</h2>
```

Comment: Please remove that **onload** attribute or I will eat you.

Comment: @PDKnight sorry ..i was removed the onload