# javascript fade between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

first of all i'm pretty new with JS. I'm buillding a website and it has a intro. This intro animation have to be placed in a different page and after it ends then the next webpage will be automatically loaded.

```
<body onload="setTimeout(
function(){
    window.location.href = 'file:///C:/Users/skatto/Desktop/art%20contest/art_contest_page.html';
}, 32000 )">
```

this is the script i'm using on my html file to automatically load the next page,
but it's pretty 'sharp' and rough, how could I add a fade animation? To make it smoother

Comment: please provide your code and tell us what you have tried so far

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the 'script'

Comment: take a look at this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805482/css3-transition-animation-on-load

Comment: you can't really fade a pageload. You can either make it a one-page application or fade in a new website onLoad...

Comment: @noa-dev: Actually most modern browsers allow a fadein on load, but that is not the point here.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="revealTrans(Duration=2.0,Transition=12)">` in your document `<head>` hehe :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple CSS can do this. why use scripts? Add the animation `fadeIn` to any body of page you want to fade in before load.

```css
body {
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s linear;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>Something
  <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

on page 1:

```
<a href="otherPage.html" class="transition">LINK</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");

    $("body").fadeIn(2000);

    $("a.transition").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```