# Why does this CSS a::after show transition after hovering?

Tags: html, css

I found some code for a link hover effect and while it works fine, I don't understand why it works.

Specifically:

```
#navbar a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;  
    -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
    transform: scale(0,1);

}

#navbar a:hover:after {

    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

This produces an underline effect on the link when hovering.

My question is:
1.) Why doesn't the transition/transform on the a:after take place when the page loads?  Why does it only occur when hovering over the element (even though it's not within the hover)?

Although I can obviously see what is occurring from viewing the page, trying to better understand how exactly this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added one fiddle where you can go and check the code

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/vickykumarui/96xw3fzv/][1]
```

Now let me explain what is happening on hover

Initially you have add this code for pseudo element after

```
transform: scale(0.1); // The scale() function is specified with either one or two values, which represent the amount of scaling to be applied in each direction.
opacity: 1; // initially after element is not visible
```

Now on hover this property changes to

```
 transform: scale(0.9);
 opacity: 1;
```

When these properties changes it does not changes suddenly but it changes slowly in .35s in animated way from this code

```
 transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
```

transition is applied on both property opacity and transform and 0.35s is time of transition

Note: Based on your comment if you change initial property to

```
opacity: 1;
 transform: scale(0.9);
```

You see that coming initially also

Comment: But doesn't that transition apply when the page loads (not during hover) since the transition isn't within the a:hover:after?  Why would a transition in a:after apply to the hover?  That's what I'm not getting.

Comment: No because transition will be applied only when that property mentioned in transition changes

Comment: Oh I see now.  I guess I assumed it applies during the initial transform/opacity within the a:after.  Thanks.

Comment: Cheers, if you want to achieve transition on page load this is what you can try
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805482/css3-transition-animation-on-load

Answer (score 0):

It does happen. Change the opacity  to 1 in the first rule. You don't see it because it's technically hidden when the page loads. When you hover, the opacity becomes one and becomes visible.

Comment: I've tried changing the opacity to 1 in the a:after and it still does not look any different.  That's part of what I'm confused about.  Now if I remove the transform: scale(0,1), it does, but that has a 0.35s transition and I don't see the underline at all when the page loads.  Can't understand why they'd include a transition in a:after since it's not even seen until you hover.