# CSS Border Transition On Page Load?

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

I would like to make a timed border draw animation once my page is loaded. I basically want the border of the div container to be hidden and then have the container border drawn through a transition, triggered by the page being loaded (without hovering). I was able to find how to do this upon hovering, but I can't figure out how to do it upon page load. How would I implement that into the following code?

```
<div id="profile-content">
     Insert Content Here
 </div>

 #profile-content
 {
     border: 3px solid;
     border-color: #FFFFFF;
     padding: 4em 4em 4em 14em;
     margin: 0 0 0 4em;
 }
```

Comment: You would _start_ by properly explaining what you want _“a timed border draw animation”_ to actually look like. And then you would tell us what _your_ research has turned up so far, and what results your own attempts yielded. Please go read [ask].

Comment: Just edited it. My apologies for the vaguely worded question. @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to look into the border transition, I just showed a couple.

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/animating-border/)

There is a property `transition` and it accepts the `seconds` as parameters to give you the effect.

```css
#profile-content {
  outline: solid 5px #FC5185;
  transition: outline 0.6s linear;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

#profile-content:hover {
  outline-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="profile-content">
  Insert Content Here
</div>
```

OR

`Div` border transition:

```css
div {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #f45e61;
  color: #f45e61;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: auto;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#profile-content {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s;
  transition: color 0.25s;
}

#profile-content::before,
#profile-content::after {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#profile-content::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#profile-content::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#profile-content:hover {
  color: Teal;
}

#profile-content:hover::before,
#profile-content:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#profile-content:hover::before {
  border-top-color: black;
  border-right-color: black;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
  transition: width 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
}

#profile-content:hover::after {
  border-bottom-color: black;
  border-left-color: black;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s;
  transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s;
}
```

```html
<div id="profile-content">
  Insert Content Here
</div>
```

Comment: So I want to be able to do the second transition without hovering. Drawing the border of the div container upon loading the page for a set amount of time. Sorry for vaguely wording the question. @manjuboyz

Comment: I am afraid you don't have many options, you need to create a js or jq function to do that job! because a event should happen to have a transition in our case it's hover.

Comment: Found one answer here it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805482/css3-transition-animation-on-load

Comment: Hope above url may help you!