# Keyframe Animation Not Working On Inner-Div On Page Load

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to use the solution to this question:

[css3 transition animation on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805482/css3-transition-animation-on-load/12638711#12638711)

And I have the following as my **HTML** and **CSS**:

```css
@keyframes slideInFromRight {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

.announcements-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 1001;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 300px;
    /* animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromRight; */
}

.announcments-1 {
    animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromRight;
}

.announcements-2 {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.annoucements-header {
    background-color: #1481C3;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
    padding: 7px 10px;
}

.annoucements-close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .85;
}
.annoucements-close:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.annoucements-close::before,
.annoucements-close::after {
    content: '';
    width: 24px;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 0;
}
.annoucements-close::before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.annoucements-close::after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="announcements-container">
    <div class="announcements-1">
      <div class="annoucements-header">
        <span class="annoucement-type-quantity">2 School Announcements</span>
        <i class="annoucements-close"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="announcements-2">
      <div class="annoucements-header">
        <span class="annoucement-type-quantity">1 Admin Annoucement</span>
        <i class="annoucements-close"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

As you can see, it doesn't do anything when `animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromRight;` gets applied to an inner-div. It does, however, work when applied to the container div:

```css
@keyframes slideInFromRight {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

.announcements-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 1001;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 300px;
    animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromRight;
}

.announcments-1 {
    /*animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromRight;*/
}

.announcements-2 {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.annoucements-header {
    background-color: #1481C3;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
    padding: 7px 10px;
}

.annoucements-close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .85;
}
.annoucements-close:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.annoucements-close::before,
.annoucements-close::after {
    content: '';
    width: 24px;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 0;
}
.annoucements-close::before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.annoucements-close::after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="announcements-container">
    <div class="announcements-1">
      <div class="annoucements-header">
        <span class="annoucement-type-quantity">2 School Announcements</span>
        <i class="annoucements-close"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="announcements-2">
      <div class="annoucements-header">
        <span class="annoucement-type-quantity">1 Admin Annoucement</span>
        <i class="annoucements-close"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

But the issue with that, is that I want for the divs to slide in one after another, sequentially. And if I 'X' out of the top div, I'll want for the second div to slide up and take its place, which is why I'm assuming a container div is necessary.

Is there anything else I can do to make the animation apply to the child divs, one at a time? 
Is there something about keyframes that prevents animation on inner-divs? Is it better to do this with JavaScript?

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/avws6h3f/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may seem odd in the first place but there is a typo in your stylesheets. **Where you declare `announcements-1` but used `announcments-1` to style it**.

So making this right will give what you wanted:

```css
@keyframes slideInFromRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.announcements-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 1001;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  /*animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromRight;*/
}

.announcements-1 {
  animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromRight;
}

.announcements-2 {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.annoucements-header {
  background-color: #1481C3;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Bold";
  padding: 7px 10px;
}

.annoucements-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .85;
}

.annoucements-close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.annoucements-close::before,
.annoucements-close::after {
  content: '';
  width: 24px;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 0;
}

.annoucements-close::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.annoucements-close::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="announcements-container">
    <div class="announcements-1">
      <div class="annoucements-header">
        <span class="annoucement-type-quantity">2 School Announcements</span>
        <i class="annoucements-close"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="announcements-2">
      <div class="annoucements-header">
        <span class="annoucement-type-quantity">1 Admin Annoucement</span>
        <i class="annoucements-close"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```