# How to show an svg element with an fade in?

Tags: html, css, animation

I have an svg element. How can i show it gradually (like an animation) from left to right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS @keyframes.

```css
@keyframes stretchInFromLeft {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}


img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 stretchInFromLeft;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  background: #fff;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dta2g.jpg" />
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r034wcgp/1/

Source: [css3 transition animation on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805482/css3-transition-animation-on-load)

Comment: ok. i have another question. how can i start animation from start? it starts not from the start point

Answer (score 1):

You could animate a SVG [clipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking#Creating_clips) with jQuery [animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) like this:

```js
$("#cut-off-bottom rect").animate({width: "100%", duration:4000})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">

<clipPath id="cut-off-bottom">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="0" height="320" />
</clipPath>

<path fill="#0099ff" fill-opacity="1" clip-path="url(#cut-off-bottom)" d="M0,32L48,32C96,32,192,32,288,58.7C384,85,480,139,576,154.7C672,171,768,149,864,165.3C960,181,1056,235,1152,240C1248,245,1344,203,1392,181.3L1440,160L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z"></path>
</svg>
```